# login to wordpress through facebook

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I want in my wordpress website that user can log in through their facebook account,,

that means when the user click the button connect through facebook account on my website ,, it will create a user with exactly the same credentials that of facebook.

Thanks

Comment: Most FB plugins for WP don't work this way. You won't be able to copy a user from FB to your WP install - instead it'll allow a user to authenticate via FB and then let your WP install know that they're authenticated and who they are. Copying the authentication info from FB to your site is a huge security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this wordpress plugin --

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/screenshots/

Comment: I think this plugin might work ,, i will check it then confirm thanks

Comment: @ShehzadBilal you can also chk this listing ---    http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=facebook+connect&sort=